# Assign fetch response to setState in React componentdidmount function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, setstate

I should start out by saying I'm pretty new to React.

When a component mounts, I need to fetch an API endpoint, and assign the JSON response to state data.  Ultimately, I need to pass the JSON response to another component.

I've tried putting the fetch directly in the componentDidMount() function but that did not work.  Below, you can see the error generated in the console.  This is at line 25 `console.log("This data => " + JSON.stringify(this.state.data));`

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')`

Any insight into how I can pass the response of /profile/:id to the ResultsDashboard component would be helpful.

Below is the code I have for my component.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {  Tabs } from 'antd';
import { ResultsDashboard } from './ResultsDashboard.js'


export class TestResults extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super (props);
        
    }
    getProfileData (){
        console.log("Making a fetch for URL /profile/" + window.location.href.split('/')[4])
        fetch('/profile/' + window.location.href.split('/')[4]).then( response => {
          console.log("Response in Fetch => " + JSON.stringify(response))
          this.setState({data:  response.json()})
          this.setState({urls: this.getUrls()}); 
        });
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getProfileData();
    }
    getUrls(){
        const urls = [];
        console.log("This data => " + JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
        for (var x = 0; x < this.state.data.length; x++){
            urls.push(this.state.data[x].url)
        }
        return urls
    }
    render (){
        
        return(
            <div>
                <Tabs
                    defaultActiveKey="1"
                    type="card"
                    size="large"
                    items={this?.state?.urls?.map((url,index) => {
                      return {
                          label: `${url.substr(0,75)}`,
                          key: index,
                          children: <ResultsDashboard testIndex={index} aggregateData={this.state.data}/>
                      };
                  })}
                  
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `.then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {...}`

And its better to change `this.getUrls()` to `this.getUrls(data)`, cause the  value of `this.state.data` might not be update yet.

```js
getProfileData() {
  console.log("Making a fetch for URL /profile/" + window.location.href.split("/")[4]);
  fetch("/profile/" + window.location.href.split("/")[4])
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Response in Fetch => " + JSON.stringify(response));
      this.setState({ data: data });
      this.setState({ urls: this.getUrls(data) });
    });
}
```

Also, remember to add `this.state = { data: {}, urls: [] };` in `constructor()`.

Comment: This worked.  I'm seeing the data now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are assigning a function to **urls**.

You can try using **this.setState** in the **getUrls** function assigning **urls** variable and passing data as argument

```
getProfileData (){
    console.log("Making a fetch for URL /profile/" + window.location.href.split('/')[4])
    fetch('/profile/' + window.location.href.split('/')[4]).then( response => {
      console.log("Response in Fetch => " + JSON.stringify(response))
      this.setState({data:  response.json()})
      this.getUrls(response.json()); 
    });
}

getUrls(data){
    const myVar = [];
    console.log("This data => " + JSON.stringify(data));
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++){
        myVar.push(data[x].url)
    }
    this.setState({urls: myVar})
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  Unfortunately that did not work.  The issue I'm seeing is that the `response` is never a json object.  Though I've confirmed via the Network Tab in Dev Tools that there is in fact a JSON object returned.  Any ideas why this.setState({data:  response.json()}) does not work?

Comment: I just changed the answer please look at passing data as argument of your function

Comment: The point is that this.setState() is an asynchronous function, so you cannot use it just after or it will probably be null, you need to call your function with the response or change your logic loading theses data